# From the Function result, From tuple to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've tried to solve this simple situation for few hours...
Not easy for me at all, so I need a help.

I'm new to python...

when I try to use the return value to the DataFrame(A)
instead of doing DataFrame('Product Type':['new product'] ......)

the results are in tuple even it is a dictionary in the function.
How can I get the dictionary, not the dictionary inside the tuple?

```
x.py
    def xxx(A):
        b = A
        b1 = b
        p =['new product']
        c = b*p
        L1 ={'Product Type':c}
        
        #
        b2 = b
        p1 =['310']
        c1 = b2*p1
        L2 ={'Price':c1}
        ...
        ...
        ...
        return L1,L2~L19
         
y.py

import x

B = x.xxx(15)
print(B)
```

## The results are in the form of the tuple

({'Product Type': ['new product','new product','new product']....})

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. I get a plain `dict`, not inside a `tuple`. How do you know what `A` is after `A = xxx(3)`? Also having something inside: `( ... )` does not make it a tuple.

Comment: I get a dict when i try

Comment: oh What I mean was that When I'm using it From other script.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why or how you are getting the answer as it works exactly as expected for me.... Is it the actual code? If not its some other problems.

Also, what leads you to think its a array, because if an array is with one element, it is always followed by an ',' (comma) but the output you mentioned doesn't have it.

```
a = {'key':'value'}
b = (a, )
print(b)
```

would result in

```
({'key':'value'},)
```

If that is just a typo, try indexing like:

```
return L1[0]
```

This would work if it is an array.

Comment: A multi-valued function always return a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

## You get a tuple because your function return more than one value!

**Multi-valued functions return their multiple values as a tuple.**
If you want to get each of the values separately you must code something like

```
B1,B2,....,B19 = x.xxx(15)
```

so each value returned by your function is assigned to one and only one output variable. Each of the **B1...B19** will receive the **L1...L19** dictionaries as output.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I've found the answer.

From the y.py

```
T1 = x.xxx(7)
LT1 = len(T1)
Todic = {}

for i in T1:
    T1 = i
    print('T1 =',T1)
```

results in dics
{'x':'xxx','xxx',.....}

Comment: Nothing different from my answer. You get a tuple because your function returns multiple values.